# Compute $\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty}{\int_0^n{\frac{x\sin(1/(nx))}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)}}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}x\,\sin\left(1 \over nx\right)\,
{\mathrm{d}x \over \,\sqrt{\, x^{2} + 1\,}\,}
$$

- I tried to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem but I get that for
  $0\leq x \leq 1$, i.e. for $n = 1$ the dominating function is
  $x/\sqrt{\, x^{2} + 1\,}$ while for $n \geq 2$ I cannot find a dominating function which is integrable i.e. $g \in L^{1}$, as $x/\sqrt{\,x^{2} + 1\,}$ has integral equal to infinity for $x \geq 1$.
- Also, for $n \geq 2$, I could only get that the functions $f_{n}$ are less than one, so I couldn't find a dominating function. 
  Could you help me to solve this problem ?.

Thank you !.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(1/(nx)) \rightarrow 1/(nx)$ done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The change of variables $x = 1/(ny)$ shows the integral equals

$$\frac{1}{n}\int_{1/n^2}^\infty \frac{\sin y}{\sqrt { 1+(ny)^2}y^2}\, dy.$$

Answer (score 2):

> Herein, we present a way forward, which is less elegant, but as effective as changing variables.

Note that we can write simply

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^n \frac{x\sin(1/(nx))}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx\right|&\le \frac1n\int_0^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1n \log\left(n+\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)\\\\
&\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering! I understand that absolute value of an integral is less than or equal to the integral of absolute value, so we get that the original expression is less than or equal to $\int_0^n{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$. As I'm rusty with integral inequalities, however, I don't understand how do you get the expression $\frac{1}{n} \int_0^n{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$. Thanks again!

Comment: Recall that $|\sin(x)|\le x$.  So, $$|\sin(1/(nx))|\le \frac1{nx}$$

Comment: @mimi .d. You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: And feel free to up vote as you see fit.  ;-)